# React js TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6, frontend

I am developing a site where posts of users with their email will appear in the screen, when a button is clicked it will go to the details of that specific post. I can change the route but it is not giving me the details. Rather it is saying that the variable decleared in PostDetails.js named 'id' is undefined.

App.js code

`

```js
//app.js code
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import AllPosts from './Components/AllPosts/AllPosts';
import NoMatch from './Components/NoMatch/NoMatch';
import PostDetails from './Components/PostDetails/PostDetails';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/'>
          <AllPosts></AllPosts>
        </Route>
        <Route to='/PostDetails/:id'>
            <PostDetails></PostDetails>
        </Route>
        <Route path='*'>
            <NoMatch></NoMatch>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
     
  )
}

export default App;

//ShowPost.js code
```

`

ShowPost.js code

`

```js
//ShowPost.js code

 import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const ShowPost = (props) => {
const {title, id} = props.post;
return (
    <div>
        <h1>{title}</h1>
        <p>{id}</p>
        <button><Link to={`/PostDetails/${id}`}>Click</Link></button>
    </div>
);
};

export default ShowPost;
```

```js
//PostDetails.js code

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const PostDetails = () => {
    let {id} = useParams();
    const {singlePost,setSinglePost} = useState();
    useEffect(()=>{
        fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setSinglePost(data))
    },[])
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>This is details {singlePost.id} </h1>
        </div>
    );
};

export default PostDetails;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing a default empty value for `singlePost` and ensure you can console log the return data from `fetch`

```
const {singlePost,setSinglePost} = useState('');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an initial state to what you want your post to show by default, for example

```
const {singlePost,setSinglePost} = useState({title: "Loading", id: "Loading"});
```

If you do not want to show the post while the post is being fetched, you can do conditional rendering of the component. Then you can use your current way of setting state: `const {singlePost,setSinglePost} = useState();` , and render the post conditionally:

```
return (
    <div>
        {singlePost ? <h1>This is details {singlePost.id} </h1> : null}
    </div>
);
```

This will hide the post until it is fetched.

To your initial question: `singlePost` will be `undefined` and trying to reach the property `id` will yield an error. This is because fetch is async and will not set the state immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the answers above do not mention the most crucial thing - `useState` hook **does not** return an object, **you can't use** an object destructuring since `useState` returns an `array`. You will have to use array destructuring instead.

> wrong:

```
const { singlePost, setSinglePost } = useState('');
```

> correct:

```
const [singlePost, setSinglePost] = useState('');
```